# Android NDK: undefined reference to 'stderr'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

I want to use the ASI SDK (prebuilt binary) in an Android application. I am using Android Studio 2.1.3 on Windows 10 with the gradle "experimental plugin" and Android NDK r12b.

My JNI test method that calls a basic SDK function looks as follows:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ASICamera2.h>

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_at_wana_androguide_MainActivity_getMsgFromJni(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance)
{
   char str[512];

   int numCams = ASIGetNumOfConnectedCameras();
   snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "Connected cameras: %d", numCams);

   return env->NewStringUTF(str);
}
```

The `build.gradle` for the `app` module looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 24
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "at.wana.androguide"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 19
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 24
            versionCode 1
            versionName "0.1"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
            }
        }
        ndk {
            moduleName "hello-android-jni"
            abiFilters.add("arm64-v8a")
            abiFilters.add("x86")
            stl "gnustl_static"
        }
        sources {
            main {
                jni {
                    dependencies {
                        library "ASISDK" linkage "static"
                        project ":usb" linkage "shared"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
            ASISDK {
                headers.srcDir "src/main/jni/drivers/ASI/include"
                binaries.withType(StaticLibraryBinary) {
                    staticLibraryFile = file("src/main/jni/drivers/ASI/lib/${targetPlatform.getName()}/libASICamera2.a")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
}
```

Since the ASI SDK depends on `libusb`, I also added the `libusb` sources as a separate module and imported is as a dependency into the `app` module. This is the `build.gradle` file for the `libusb` module (called "usb"):

```
apply plugin: "com.android.model.native"

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 24
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

        ndk {
            moduleName "usb"

            CFlags.add("-I${file("src/main/jni")}".toString())
            CFlags.add("-I${file("src/main/jni/os")}".toString())

            ldLibs.addAll(["log"])
        }
    }
}
```

Problem:

This code builds OK, but when I run it in Genymotion (x86), Android 5, it crashes with a runtime exception:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol
>   "stderr" referenced by "libhello-android-jni.so"..

I tried adding `supc++` and/or `stdc++` to `ldFlags`, I tried changing the filename extension to `cpp` and back to `c`, and I already tried setting the `platformVersion` to 19 or even 9 in the build.gradle files, but this only resulted in a *compile time error* saying that `stderr` is not defined:

> C:\Users\greuff\Documents\devel\AndroGuide\app\src\main\jni\drivers\ASI\lib\x86\libASICamera2.a(ASICamera2.o):ASICamera2.cpp:function
>   ASIGetNumOfConnectedCameras: error: undefined reference to 'stderr'
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Curiously, this error only occurs for the `x86` platform target.

I read that `stderr` etc were removed from Android NDK Headers at a certain point in time because they became real functions in `libc`, but I'm not quite sure how to solve this problem since setting `platformVersion` to a lower value (as suggested in some questions) did not help. I would be very grateful for pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out I was chasing the wrong thing. The ASI SDK was statically compiled against the glibc which contains `stderr` as globally available symbols, whereas bionic (the Android libc) doesn't contain them.

All I had to do was to undefine `stderr` and created it myself as a linker symbol, so the linker can find it:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ASICamera2.h>

#undef stderr
FILE *stderr = &__sF[2];

...
```

Comment: "The ASI SDK was statically compiled against the glibc". That library was compiled for Linux then, not Android. This is going to be an uphill battle for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had such problems when there were different platform versions used in cmake command with the next argument -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=21 and min sdk specified in the Android project build.gradle file. Make sure that you are using consistent versions.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue with a library that was linking `stderr` but leaving the symbol undefined. Since `stderr` definition is part of stdio, it should always be defined but CMake is configured to throw on unknown symbols.

You can suppress the error by configuring CMake in `build.gradle` like so:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DANDROID_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=ON"
            }
        }
    }
}
```